# RecyclerView adapter not working with butter knife

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter, butterknife

why RecyclerView adapter not working with ButterKnife ?

It's working with findViewById but not working with ButterKnife

Adapter Class

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.viewHolder>{

    Context context;
    List<CategoriesModels> categoriesModels;

    public CategoriesAdapter(Context context,List<CategoriesModels> categoriesModels){
        this.context = context;
        this.categoriesModels = categoriesModels;
    }

    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_categories, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder viewHolder = new viewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoriesModels.size();
    }

    class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.img_flag)
        ImageView img_flag;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_title)
        TextView txt_title;
        @BindView(R.id.img_correct)
        ImageView img_correct;

        public viewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(context,view);
        }

    }

}
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class CategoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.txt_select_language)
    TextViewFont txt_select_language;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_categories)
    RecyclerView rv_categories;

    List<CategoriesModels> categoriesModels = new ArrayList<>();
    CategoriesAdapter categoriesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
        ButterKnife.bind(CategoriesActivity.this);
        //show data
        ShowDate();
    }

    private void ShowDate() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://*****").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        RetrofitService retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
        Call<List<CategoriesModels>> call = retrofitService.get_categories();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CategoriesModels>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CategoriesModels>> call, Response<List<CategoriesModels>> response) {
                List<CategoriesModels> list = response.body();
                for (CategoriesModels i : list) {
                    categoriesModels.add(new CategoriesModels(i.getId(), i.getTitle(), i.getPhoto(), i.getShortcut()));
                }
                categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(CategoriesActivity.this, categoriesModels);
                rv_categories.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CategoriesActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                rv_categories.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CategoriesModels>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I tried a lot before putting up the subject but I did not find a solution yet....................................................................................

Comment: From the documentation:
public static Unbinder bind(java.lang.Object target,
                            android.view.View source)
BindView annotated fields and methods in the specified target using the source View as the view root.
Parameters:
target - Target class for view binding.
source - View root on which IDs will be looked up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

inside viewHolder constructor replace context to be this

```
ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
```

this refer to ViewHolder class which contain view you want to inject!\

Take a look to ButterKnife Examples. 
https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/